# Why if I apply the shape method to an array with only an element, it returns an empty tuple?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a list S. In the second element there is another list containing several arrays. If I print `S[1][4].shape[0]` program returns an empty tuple, but if I print `S[1][4]` program returns a number. Type of `S[1][4]` is `nd.array`.
Why doesn't shape method return <1>?

Comment: So where is your code?

Answer (score 3):

`numpy` arrays can have a 0 dimensions, in which case the shape tuple will be `()`.  If it is a 1d array, it can have `(1,)` shape.

Compare the shape of these 3 arrays:

```
np.array(3)
np.array([3])
np.array([[3]])
```

They all have 1 element, but `.ndim` and `.shape` are different.